# Import Firefox bookmarks from windows 7 (unbootable) to ubuntu using ubuntu

Tags: mount, windows-7, firefox, bookmarks

I have already googled the question and got an incredible answer but I have a problem with replicating it. My windows directory is on the partition called 'OS' and my username is Siba while the firefox profile is 'r0hktjlz.default'.
Basically it goes like this:

```
OS/Users/Siba/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/r0hktjlz.default
```

How should I rewrite the Terminal text that is in the answer?

The answer is from *PleaseStand*:

> Assuming that your Windows partition is mounted as /mnt and that your Windows username is hey, first copy the (randomly named) old profile directory to your Ubuntu account:
>
> `cp -r /mnt/Users/hey/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/*.default ~/.mozilla/firefox/win7profile`
>
> Then quit Firefox and edit the ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini file, changing StartWithLastProfile=1 to StartWithLastProfile=0 and adding the following to the end:
>
> `[Profile1]
>   Name=win7profile
>   IsRelative=1
>   Path=win7profile`
>
> Restart Firefox. It should then allow you to select which profile you want to use.

Comment: Just copy content of firefox directory from Windows partition to /home/user/.mozzilla/firefox ... relatively the same location and after that try starting "firefox -p" and select profile yourself ... in my case: Alt + F2 and then typing  "firefox -p"

Comment: Yes, I don't get it. Am I supposed to have a new Firefox window show itself after typing 'firefox -p'?

I tried typing it in Terminal as well and:   
(process:5347): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Comment: just little windows with profile selection. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/JLvFKzx.png?1

Comment: Doeas firefox run normally? Try renaming .mozzilla to something like .mozzillabackup and start firefox again.

Comment: Firefox is running normally. I don't know if it's relevant but my windows 7 can't be booted. Off-topic: do you know how to change the folder/partition that software&updates download into?

Comment: just restarted my computer and I get the small window where I can choose profile but only the default profile is there. Default has no bookmarks.

Comment: / is root... /home is where Downloads are located, sorry but I dont quite understand, what you wanna do - change Firefox download location? Unbootable Windows shouldnt be an issue in case of copying files from its partition.

Comment: you need to copy content of C:/Users/Username/Appdata/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/XXXXX - it should be like this I guess, cant check it ... to /home/user/.mozzilla/firefox .... then I would open profiles.ini and copy the content of the profile0 below, rename it to profile1, give it name you want and under path write name of profile you have copied from Windows

Comment: I will try it via VM, wait a sec!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it works just I as tought!

1. Go to and copy
   *C:/Users/Username/Appdata/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/**nameofprofile.default***
2. Copy your file you retrieved from Windows partition to */home/user/.mozzilla/firefox*
3. open profiles.ini and modify to something like:

   ```
   [General]
   StartWithLastProfile=1

   [Profile0]
   Name=default
   IsRelative=1
   Path=avjdkb26.default

   [Profile1]
   Name=NEW
   IsRelative=1
   Path=nameofprofile.default
   Default=1
   ```
4. Run "firefox -p" and selectyour profile

Line `Default=1` determines which profile is set as default

Comment: This is very much appreciated and I'd be jumping through burning hoops right now from joy IF I had a /.mozilla/firefox path.

Comment: open file manager  - click View tab and mark "Show hidden files", or Ctrl + H shortcut might work for you

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank You! Wow even my 'session:restore' and all the tabs I had up are back. You deserve a Gold medal.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped!

Answer (score 0):

**To import your firefox bookmarks:**

1. Go to the bookmar menu/icon and select show all bookmars to open the bookmar manager.
2. Select the import/backup option and Import the bookmarks, copy them to Ubuntu.
3. Open firefox in your Ubuntu install and do the same except you select import now.

Comment: He cant boot Windows :)

Comment: @MichalHagara that would be an insteresting detail for the OP to incluide in his question.