# How do I recover my access to google groups?

Tags: networking, permissions, firefox

Since creating a google group and setting up a non-privileged alias logon, I now the following error message which revokes my access to all of my groups: -

"This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.groups.google.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate."

How do I recover my access?

Comment: Read the Firefox error.  HSTS is enabled on the site but the SSL certificate is invalid.  Nuke your browser cache completely and try again.  If it still fails the issue is a remote site issue and not one fixable here

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear your history and cache

   - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache
   - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox

**If that won't help, proceed to step 2.**

2. What often help in terms of firefox issues is creating a new profile:

   - open terminal
   - type: `firefox -p`
   - create new profile and set it as default
   - start firefox
   - try to login via new profile

---

If you can't get `firefox -p` to work:

- close Firefox
- enter `firefox -CreateProfile user` in terminal, where "user" is name (don't use space in profile name) of your new profile, that step will create new profile, but will not launch the application
- next I'm going to refer to my answer about manually modifying Firefox profile: [Import Firefox bookmarks from windows 7 (unbootable) to ubuntu using ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621628/import-firefox-bookmarks-from-windows-7-unbootable-to-ubuntu-using-ubuntu/621656#621656), but YOU WILL SKIP the step no. 4. And you will manually add line `Default=1` to you new profile, as seen in my referred answer (as well as delete this line from your old profile).

**Alternatively you can try to enter this to terminal**: `firefox -P "user"`, which will open firefox with your new profile, but those changes won't be permanent, so it's good just for testing purposes, to see, if you can regain your google access that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong URL.  The correct URL is `https://groups.google.com`, **without** the www.